# Symfony 2 Transformer on entity form type

Tags: php, forms, symfony, transform, symfony-2.5

I'm trying to create a new form type in Symfony 2. It is based on entity type, it uses [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) on frontend and I need the user to be able to select existing entity or create the new one.

My idea was to send entity's id and let it to be converted by the default entity type if user select existing entity or send something like "_new:entered text" if user enter new value. Then this string should be converted to the new form entity by my own model transformer, which should look something like this:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\MainBundle\Form\DataTransformer;

use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;

class EmptyEntityTransformer
implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    private $entityName;
    public function __construct($entityName)
    {
        $this->entityName = $entityName;
    }
    public function transform($val)
    {
        return $val;
    }
    public function reverseTransform($val)
    {
        $ret = $val;
        if (substr($val, 0, 5) == '_new:') {
            $param = substr($val, 5);
            $ret = new $this->entityName($param);
        }
        return $ret;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the transformer is only called when existing entity is selected. When I enter a new value, the string is sent in the request but transformer's reverseTransform method is not called at all.

I'm new to Symfony so I don't even know if this approach is correct. Do you have any Idea how to solve this?

edit:
My form type code is:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\MainBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Acme\MainBundle\Form\DataTransformer\EmptyEntityTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

class Select2EntityType
extends AbstractType
{
    protected $router;
    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        parent::setDefaultOptions($resolver);
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'placeholder' => null,
            'path' => false,
            'pathParams' => null,
            'allowNew' => false,
            'newClass' => false,
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'entity';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 's2_entity';
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        if ($options['newClass']) {
            $transformer = new EmptyEntityTransformer($options['newClass']);
            $builder->addModelTransformer($transformer);
        }
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $field = $view->vars['name'];
        $parentData = $form->getParent()->getData();
        $opts = array();
        if (null !== $parentData) {
            $accessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
            $val = $accessor->getValue($parentData, $field);
            if (is_object($val)) {
                $getter = 'get' . ucfirst($options['property']);
                $opts['selectedLabel'] = $val->$getter();
            }
            elseif ($choices = $options['choices']) {
                if (is_array($choices) && array_key_exists($val, $choices)) {
                    $opts['selectedLabel'] = $choices[$val];
                }
            }
        }

        $jsOpts = array('placeholder');

        foreach ($jsOpts as $jsOpt) {
            if (!empty($options[$jsOpt])) {
                $opts[$jsOpt] = $options[$jsOpt];
            }
        }
        $view->vars['allowNew'] = !empty($options['allowNew']);
        $opts['allowClear'] = !$options['required'];
        if ($options['path']) {
            $ajax = array();
            if (!$options['path']) {
                throw new \RuntimeException('You must define path option to use ajax');
            }
            $ajax['url'] = $this->router->generate($options['path'], array_merge($options['pathParams'], array(
                'fieldName' => $options['property'],
            )));
            $ajax['quietMillis'] = 250;
            $opts['ajax'] = $ajax;
        }
        $view->vars['options'] = $opts;
    }
}
```

and then I create this form type:

```
class EditType
extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('masterProject', 's2_entity', array(
                'label' => 'Label',
                'class' => 'MyBundle:MyEntity',
                'property' => 'name',
                'path' => 'my_route',
                'pathParams' => array('entityName' => 'name'),
                'allowNew' => true,
                'newClass' => '\\...\\MyEntity',
            ))
```

...

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: You need to show us FormType code also and, eventually (if you have), custom types for forms. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an answer however I'm not really sure if this is the correct solution. When I tried to understand how EntityType works I noticed that it uses EntityChoiceList to retrive list of available options and in this class there is a getChoicesForValues method which is called when ids are transformed to entities. So I implemented my own ChoiceList which adds my own class to the end of the returned array:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\MainBundle\Form\ChoiceList;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\ChoiceList\EntityChoiceList;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessorInterface;


class EmptyEntityChoiceList
extends EntityChoiceList
{
    private $newClassName = null;
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager, $class, $labelPath = null, EntityLoaderInterface $entityLoader = null, $entities = null,  array $preferredEntities = array(), $groupPath = null, PropertyAccessorInterface $propertyAccessor = null, $newClassName = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($manager, $class, $labelPath, $entityLoader, $entities, $preferredEntities, $groupPath, $propertyAccessor);
        $this->newClassName = $newClassName;
    }
    public function getChoicesForValues(array $values)
    {
        $ret = parent::getChoicesForValues($values);
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            if (is_string($value) && substr($value, 0, 5) == '_new:') {
                $val = substr($value, 5);
                if ($this->newClassName) {
                    $val = new $this->newClassName($val);
                }
                $ret[] = $val;
            }
        }
        return $ret;
    }
}
```

Registering this ChoiceList to the form type is a bit complicated because the class name of original choice list is hardcoded in the DoctrineType which EntityType extends but it is not difficult to understand how to do it if you have a look into this class.

The reason why DataTransformer is not called probably is that EntityType is capable to return array of results and transform is applied to every item of this collection. If the result array is empty,  there is obviously no item to call transformer on.

Comment: Have you found the way to achieve this?

Comment: I didn't overridden EntityChoiceList in global, i just created my own class which is extended from thesymfony's EntityChoiceList. Then I created my own form type extended from Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType and in this new form type and I overwritten setDefaultOptions method where EntityChoiceList class is instanciated and I hardcoded my own EntityChoiceList for this form type

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same question as yours, I chose to use an `FormEvent` with still a `DataTransformer`

The idea is to switch the field type (the entity one) just before the submit.

```
public function preSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();
    if (substr($data['project'], 0, 5) == '_new:') {
        $form->add('project', ProjectCreateByNameType::class, $options);
    }
}
```

This will replace the `project` field with a new custom one before the submit if needed.

`ProjectCreateByNameType` can extend a `TextField` and have to add the `DataTransformer`.